# Error converting pdf from url to image - Laravel Imagick

Tags: php, laravel-8, imagick

In my Laravel application with sail (docker),  I'm making a function to convert pdf documents to images.

The function receives a URL, which contains the pdf document.
Ex: "http://localhost:5000/my-application/hojavavida/8/documents/1676480714qhRZ57Bjl2nD673.pdf"

All these documents come from the Minio container.
I am using Imagick to do the conversion the function is as follows:

```
public function pdfToImage($pdfFilePath)    
{ 
        $imagick = new Imagick();
        $imagick->readImage($pdfFilePath);
        
        $filename = time().Str::random(15).'.'.'jpg';
        $imagick->setImageFormat('jpg');
        $imagick->writeImage(Storage::disk('tmp')->put($directory .'/'. 
        $filename, $imagick));
        dd("created");
}
```

But it returns the following message:

```
"message": "Failed to read the file",
"exception": "ImagickException",
```

I have checked that by passing another URL with a pdf document, and it is able to read it and generate the image from the document.

The Main problem:  I can't get it to read the URLs coming from my docker.

I did the requisites validation
verify if Imagick is installed on the container

```
php -i | grep imagick

imagick
imagick module => enabled
imagick module version => 3.7.0
imagick classes => Imagick, ImagickDraw, ImagickPixel, ImagickPixelIterator, ImagickKernel
imagick.allow_zero_dimension_images => 0 => 0
imagick.locale_fix => 0 => 0
imagick.progress_monitor => 0 => 0
imagick.set_single_thread => 1 => 1
imagick.shutdown_sleep_count => 10 => 10
imagick.skip_version_check => 1 => 1
```

verify GhostScript

```
which gs

/usr/bin/gs
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally and seeing that only local URLs were the problem.
so, I parse the URLs when those come from localhost and transform it to 'http://minio:9000'.

// get host from URL

```
$pdfFilePath = [];
    foreach ($urls as $url) {
        $host = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);
        if ($host == 'localhost') {
            $pdfFilePath[] = $this->transformUrl($url);
        }
    }
```

So now passing the new URL to Imagick the conversion to image is correct.

```
$imagick = new Imagick();
        $imagePaths = [];
        foreach ($pdfFilePath as $pdf) {
            $imagick->readImage($pdf);
            $filename = pathinfo($pdf, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
            $imagick->setImageFormat('jpg');
            $imagick->writeImage(public_path($directory . '/' . $filename . '.jpg'));
            $imagePaths[] = url($directory . '/' . $filename . '.jpg');
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Best solution for convert pdf to image using Imagick in Laravel

Get Pdf Path from Storage

`$pdf_path = Storage::disk('public')->path($product_asset->pdf_path);`

   
Create the Output Directory in Storage Folder

    $directory_create = Storage::disk('public')->path('products/pdf_images');
    if (!file_exists($directory_create)) {
       mkdir($directory_create, 0777, true);
    }
    $output_images = $directory_create.'/';
    
Call the imagick Lib with method to convert the high quality jpg images.

    $im = new Imagick();
    //Sets the image resolution
    $im->setResolution(250, 250);
    //Reads image from filename
    $im->readImage($pdf_path);
    $im->setImageFormat('jpg');
    $im->setImageCompression(Imagick::COMPRESSION_JPEG);
    //Sets the image compression quality.
    $im->setImageCompressionQuality(100);
    //Set the compression quality for newly created images
    $im->setCompressionQuality(100);
    //Clears all resources associated to Imagick object
    $im->clear();
    //Destroys the Imagick object
    $im->destroy();
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. What did you change and why? What makes you solution the "best solution"?

Comment: PHP imagick is useful to convert pdf to image as per our need, In this example we can get high resolution jpeg image with store in pdf_images folder.

Comment: Please add all clarification **to your answer** by editing it

Comment: @NicoHaase Thank you for guide, I have edited answer with the explanation.

Comment: Please also share why this should be the "best" solution

Comment: @NicoHaase Imagick is better compare to other extension or lib, also we can set image compress quality and image size in method. so its easy to used. Thank you,

Comment: Please add all clarification **to your answer** by editing it, especially as the OP already uses Imagick